# Using BYROW with dynamic arrays as formula inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have a column in an excel table that contains the following formula:
`=ARRAYTOTEXT(HSTACK(MAKEARRAY(1,[@[Liquidation Lag]],LAMBDA(r,c,0)),TAKE(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT([@[Default Vector]],", ")),,[@[Months to Project]]-[@[Liquidation Lag]])))`

On another worksheet, I would like to use BYROW to dynamically spill an array that extracts the embedded array within the ARRAYTOTEXT portion of the formula and spills it column-wise.  This is the formula I'm trying to use:

`=BYROW(lossModel_tbl[Liquidation Vector],LAMBDA(r,VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(r,", "))))`

I've tried various iterations of this that have involved makearray, sequence, index, etc. and I always come up with either #calc! or #value! errros.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to help you if you provide some sample data and your expected output, best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Comment: So you want a formula to spill the result of the previous, or you need the previous to return a spill range already? Regardless we need some data to reproduce.

Comment: `=DROP(REDUCE("",lossModel_tbl[Liquidation Vector],LAMBDA(s,r,VSTACK(s,VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(r,", ")))),1)`

Comment: Here is an example:

first row table row value:
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"

second table row value:
"0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0"

I would like my spilled array (row-wise), to return spilled arrays (columnwise) that convert the ", " separated text strings into arrays.  So the result of a byrow function on those two text rows would be a spilled array that looks as follows:

    C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
r1   1   2   3   4   5    0   0   0   0 
r2   0   0   0   0   0    0   0 10   0

Comment: sorry about the format here, I'm a noob on using these forums.

Comment: Here's the output that I'd like to spill from those two text strings:

| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | -- | - |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=NUMBERVALUE(IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A4)),LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A1:A4,y),","))))),,1),"0"))

This formula returns the intended result if i correctly understand what you want to do. BYROW can't be applied since it can't spill horizontally and vertically at the same time.

[image: Using REDUCE with dynamic arrays as formula inputs]

Comment: This is very close! Thank you.  I am going to have to try to unpack this! The only change I made to get the output that I sought was to transpose the whole thing, so I just wrapped the whole thing in transpose since I'd have to figure out how this works!

Comment: This one ended up being the winner I was looking for.  Very clever, again thank you for your help.

=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(loanCount),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(lossModel_tbl[Loss Vector],y),","))))),1),0)

Answer (score 5):

> **DISCLAIMER:** Due to the limitations of recursive lambdas in Excel, the methods outlined in the solution below should only be used on small datasets.

With any of the built-in dynamic array functions like `BYROW()`, if the calculation performed on each iteration of the function produces an array of results, it will return the `#CALC!` error because "Nested Arrays" are not supported.

The canned solution you'll typically find as a workaround is to use some variation of `REDUCE()` with `VSTACK()` and/or `HSTACK()`. However, this method can be difficult to comprehend, and even harder to adapt to complex scenarios.

An alternative approach would be to create a custom `LAMBDA()` function in Name Manager that behaves exactly like `BYROW()`, but with the added benefit of being able to "stack" the results of nested arrays. To do this, open Name Manager **(Ctrl + F3)** and define a new name called **STACKBYROW** with the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(array,function,[initial_value],[start],[pad_with],
   LET(
   n, IF(ISOMITTED(start), 1, start),
   f, function(INDEX(array, n, )),
   v, IF(ISOMITTED(initial_value), f, IFNA(VSTACK(initial_value, f), pad_with)),
   IF(n<ROWS(array), STACKBYROW(array, function, v, n+1, pad_with), v)))
```

The `STACKBYROW()` function can now be used in your workbook exactly as you intended to use `BYROW()`:

```
=STACKBYROW(lossModel_tbl[Liquidation Vector], LAMBDA(r, VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(r, ", "))))
```

If the results produce a "jagged array", the empty values will be filled with zeros (0) by default. Use the optional *[pad_with]* parameter to fill them with a value of your choosing, such as an empty string (""), if desired:

```
=STACKBYROW(lossModel_tbl[Liquidation Vector], LAMBDA(r, VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(r, ", "))),,, "")
```

As for the additional example presented in the comment section above, you could use:

```
=STACKBYROW(A1:A2, LAMBDA(r, --TEXTSPLIT(r, ", ")),,, "")
```

[image: stackbyrow.png]

**BONUS Example (with increased complexity):**

To demonstrate the flexibility of `STACKBYROW()`, we can use it to solve the "Ticket List Challenge" presented by Wyn Hopkins of Access Analytic back in November 2022:

[image: ticket_list_challenge.png]

**Solution:**

```
=STACKBYROW(tblTicket, LAMBDA(r,
LET(
   n, INDEX(r, 1),
   v, --TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(r, 3),"-"),
   m, MIN(v),
   IFERROR(HSTACK(n, SEQUENCE(MAX(v)-m+1,, m)), n))),
{"Name","Ticket Number"})
```

**Results:**

[image: ticket_list_solution.png]

Comment: "*this method can be difficult to comprehend*", proceeds to create a custom lambda function.. :') Great solution though. Not sure why OP mentions wanting it split in rows but then goes for a transposed result like in the other answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Notus_Panda Lol, I hear ya. This is definitely more of a “did you know this was possible” post, rather than a viable solution, as it can only handle around 1000 rows of data. I thought about deleting it, but left it in for its high geek factor and nerd appeal. ;-)